# jdk-8u161-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt.tar.gz installation issue on ubuntu 17.10.1

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 17.10.1 using VMware Workstation Pro and the first task I want to accomplish is to install `jdk-8u161-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt.tar.gz`. For the same, I followed following steps:

1. I downloaded the jdk from offical site and copied the extracted file to `/usr/lib/java` directory that I created.
2. Executed following commands:

   1. `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java" 1`
   2. `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/javac" 1`
3. Updated the `.bashrc` file with below three statements :

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_161
   set PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
   export PATH
   ```
4. Closed and re-opened the terminal and fired the command: `java -version`

Now I am getting the below error :

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * gcj-6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Am I missing anything here? Help needed..

Comment: It's self solved !! 
You can easily install java in ubuntu 17.10.1 doing `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless` that also will install a jdk

Comment: I executed the command you suggested and it got completed. But still I am facing the same error while checking the java version ( java -version)

Comment: I've run the command : `docker run -it ubuntu:17.10 bash` to as close as I can be to your case.

After an `apt update`, I installed java as instructed `apt install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless` . 

The result of `java -version is:`

`
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_162"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
`